# Spring Security OAuth - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Following is my Authorization server configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                .autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
```

And the Web security configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@Order(-20) // Very important
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().and().requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

Now, from the client application, when I try to access a secure resource, it redirects to the authorization server but I get the following error:

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

The same setup is working well in case of basic authentication. I am facing problems when I switch to form login.

## Update

The following web security setting worked.

```
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access","/oauth/token").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
```

Now, I am able to see the login page and I am able to login as well, but post login, the client is not able to get an oauth token.

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 11 17:39:46 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token
```

I am able to see the following server log

```
2016-07-11 17:39:46.119 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/css/**'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.119 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/js/**'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.119 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/images/**'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/error'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@13bb1f26
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/login'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.120 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/login'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/authorize'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/confirm_access'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [permitAll]
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6780c4c7, returned: 1
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-07-11 17:39:46.121 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-07-11 17:39:46.122 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2016-07-11 17:39:46.122 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2016-07-11 17:39:46.123  INFO 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: InsufficientAuthenticationException, There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.
2016-07-11 17:39:46.125 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-07-11 17:39:46.126 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-07-11 17:39:46.126 DEBUG 12502 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

## Update 2

Following is my client configuration.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

## Update 3

The code is available in the following repo

https://github.com/pavan496/insol-test

Comment: Try this `...antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").permitAll().and()...`

Comment: There is no `permitAll()` available after `requestMatchers().antMatchers()`

Comment: That request matcher is totally useless. Use this: `http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();`

Comment: Added this.. `http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();` Still the same error.

Comment: Use the following `http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").permitAll() .anyRequest().authenticated();`

Comment: I appreciate the effort that you are putting in but still the same error. I feel I'm missing something basic..

Comment: Hi.. You were right to some extent. I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: What is your oauth2 client configuration? Do you have everything in single application or do you have server and client applications (eg authorization server and resource server)? Are you using somewhere @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation?

Comment: I have two different applications one as authorization and resource server and another as client The client has @EnableOAuth2Sso. I have updated the client configuration in the question.

Comment: Do you  have implemented endpoint `http://localhost:9999/uaa/user`?

Comment: If possible share your code somewhere on github.

Comment: I got rid of error by removing `.anyRequest().authenticated()`. Not sure if this is applicable in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out what the problem was.

I went through the following example available on github where form based authentication mechanism was used (which is what I was looking for).

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/

The exact code is working fine if I use a non HTML page as my login page. For example, JSP or FTL. The example uses Freemarker. Everything is working fine with my settings if I use ftl pages. But the same are not working in case of .html pages.

Comment: Maybe the FTL template adds the CSRF token automatically, while in the html page, you have to add it manually. Just guessing!

Answer (score 13):

You need to make the `/login` endpoints publicly available (not authorized), users need to be able to login without being already logged in.

The `/oauth` endpoints *must* be secured.

Try the following

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login.html", "/logout.do").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .loginPage("/login.html");
 }
```

I have a spring-security-oauth example project on github, you can check it out here https://github.com/FrontierPsychiatrist/spring-oauth-example/.

Comment: I tried this. I am receiving an error stating "An OAuth 2 access token must be obtained or an exception thrown." I think the client application is trying to fire "/oauth/token" request after the /authorize request. And that is not accessible. I looked at your repo. This is not the case in it. Your approach seems to be a little different. I have shared my code in the repo mentioned in the question. Can you please take a look at it. It shouldn't be very hard to setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I was trying impl. OAuth Authorize with **grand_type=implicit**

I offer you to try follow steps for fix problems related with OAuth2 in Spring:

1. Necessary try to specify existing redirect_uri param; in OAuth2 specs it isn't required param but in spring app it should be present;
2. Opened OAuth2 access for Spring Secure login page in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (you have already done this) is required:
3. Try to make forvard ordering: ***@Order(-1)*** for extender of **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**. It fixed most of my problems in this question;

Ovveriden methods in the **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** extender:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginPage("/common/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/common/error.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/oauth/authorize")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/common/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }
```